# Creating dialog when i longclick a button from my listactivity

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an activity extends listactivity and i implemented it onitemclicklistener. It works accordingly what i want. However i want to generate extra work. I want to longclick one of the buttons on the list and generate a dialog box which is the same for all buttons. How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like a Popup menu? Like this:http://xinsight.ca/blog/images/pop-up-copy-menu.jpg

Comment: No, actually i mean like this : http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_list.png

Comment: Thanks but the major problem is not generating this spinner or dialog box. Problem is generating onItemLongClickListener because i have already had a onClick method for buttons. I want long click.